# Shimano cassette number of teeth

Tags: cassette, drivetrain

Newbie question here.

Currently on my old Tiagra 4500, I have a Shimano HG50 9-speed Cassette, with **11**-25T. I need another cassette, as I got a smart trainer, but it is a bit hard to find such a cassette. Can I use a CS-HG50 9S, but **12**-25T cassette? What will be different?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That will be fine.
The only difference is that you will lose ~9% from your top speed.  Unless you are extremely powerful and wanting to sprint at the end of esports races you will never notice that loss of top speed.

Comment: Thanks! So I can replace it without changing the chain or other parts?

Comment: You'll need a tool to tighten the lock ring.  That can either be in the form of a dedicated tool or an adapter to use with a wrench.

Comment: The chain must accomodate both largest-largest as a maximum length, and smallest-smallest as a minimum length. your smallest-smallest - length increases (-> changes inside the previous lengths), so it can stay the same.

Comment: @DanCantir People usually tell you it's a good idea to replace the chain when you're replacing the cassette. A worn chain might not mesh well with a new cassette. But if your chain is still pretty new (I have no idea if it is or not), you should be able to get away without it.

Comment: You will almost certainly need a spacer. The 11/12 adjustment is tiny enough so that the B-screw is irrelevant. I'd worry more about the spacer. What is the smart trainer model?

Comment: @ToddMinehard it's a Tacx Flux S. I have installed my curent cassette and used the spacer supplied with the trainer. It works good, but I want to buy a new cassette for the trainer and move the current one back to the wheel.


Also, I am going to replace the chain.

Comment: @AndyP, OP will also need a chainwhip to tighten the lockring on the trainer because on a trainer the cassette will rotate clockwise freely. On a wheel the free-hub will keep that from happening.